# How to put string and integer in list by user input

Tags: string, list, integer, sublist

Can you suggest me how to put integer and string in sub-list of list? For example:

Sample input:

```
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Charli
37.2
Ron
41
Jack
39
```

Sample output:

```
[['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Charli', 37.2], ['Ron', 41], ['Jack', 39]]
```

I have tried this:

```
students = []
for i in range(int(input("Enter num of students: "))):
    name = input("name of student: ")
    score = float(input("score:  "))
    students.append(name)
    students.append(score)
print(students)
```

But I am getting this:

```
['test1', 23.1, 'test2', 53.32]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)  (or `list`) instead of the single values:

```py
students = []
for i in range(int(input("Enter num of students: "))):
    name = input("name of student: ")
    score = float(input("score:  "))
    students.append((name, score))
    # students.append([name, score]) # alternatively
print(students)
```

---

I suggest to use `tuple`s instead of lists. Tuples are something similar like lists but cannot be modified after creation. I guess that this makes more sens in your example since your `(student, score)` is a data structure. Also [tuples are faster](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) because they are immutable.